# how to profile my ruby on rails site

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio, fb-graph

What's the best way to profile my RoR website http://www.karmabee.net?

I'm using the fb_graph GEM which is pretty slow, especially when retrieving friends lists. Twilio is also pretty slow when sending SMS texts.

So I'm not sure I could optimize those things. In any case, I need to figure out how to profile the site first.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Best" in what sense? And does the site itself really matter, or is there something specific about *yours* we should be taking into account? If so, the question may be too localized.

Comment: The best tools for profiling. And well, optimizing, which is what I'm going to have to do as it takes around three seconds to process a user requesting a favor on the site.

Comment: Right, "best" in what sense? What are your criteria?

Comment: Free profiling tool that's the easiest to use.

Answer (score 4):

NewRelic: http://newrelic.com/ It looks into your rails app and tells you how much time each request spends on db queries, page rendering etc. From there you can drilldown to the bottleneck and work on optimizations.

http://www.webpagetest.org/ is handy for general page speed testing.

Chrome comes with the Audits tool(right click, inspect element -> Audits tab) which you can test any webpage's webpage performance and network utilization. Firefox has an addon [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) does something similar.

Not sure how interaction with twilio can be profiled...

Comment: Wow, NewRelic looks very promising. I'll definitely be trying it out.

Comment: Yea, it is also what I've been using for my projects. Apart from the useful metrics it provides, it comes free and is [easily integratable with heroku apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic).

Answer (score 2):

I really like [request log analyzer](https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer/), just do:

```
gem install request-log-analyzer
```

Then on your production box you can do something like:

```
request-log-analyzer log/production.log
```

It'll tell you all sorts of things like which controllers and actions are slow, etc, give it a try!